# How to change a JSON timestamp with a T in it to Normal Date and Time in excel

Tags: json, excel, datetime, timestamp, excel-2010

Hi I have a timestamp in the format:

**2020-03-20T10:05:52.4072849+00:00** how do i convert this to normal date and time in **excel**

I tried below:

```
     1. =MID(F2,8,10)

     2.  =(C2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400
```

None work, PLease help

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(F9,1,FIND(".",F9,1)-1),"T"," ")`  .. will give you text.. You can convert it to timevalue by multiplying by 1 ... Then you can format it as you want

Comment: If you want time out of it you can use this with the result value (after multiplying by 1)  `=MOD(result,1)` ... so you can get date with `=result-MOD(result,1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is a string because of the `T`.

So we need to split the two parts.
Since the date and time formats are unambiguous, we can use the `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` functions.

```
  =DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1)-1))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("T",A1)+1,12))
```

or, more obscure but with fewer functions, convert the string into something Excel will understand:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1),"T"," ")
```